# Internet in ESP32 is not working with IPv6

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, wifi, espressif

I am using ESP-WROOM-32D in STA mode with Arduino IDE(2.0.5) ESP32 board(2.0.9).
I am trying to do http post request with ESP32. Router that provides internet supports only IPv6.

Here I am getting http code -1. I have tried different network with IPv4 which works fine and returns 200.

So my question is do I need to enable something to make this work ? I have used WiFi.enableIpV6(); and got IPv6 IP also.

```
void setup() {


Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(2000);
  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(300);
    Serial.println(".");
  }
  Serial.println("wifi connected");
  delay(2000);
  
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("https://www.google.com/");
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  Serial.printf("HTTP code: %d\n", httpCode);
  http.end();
}

void loop() {

}

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event) {
  switch (event) {
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_CONNECTED:
      Serial.println("Enabling IPv6");
      WiFi.enableIpV6();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

This is the debug message I got

```
[     4][D][esp32-hal-cpu.c:244] setCpuFrequencyMhz(): PLL: 480 / 2 = 240 Mhz, APB: 80000000 Hz
[  2053][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 0 - WIFI_READY
[  2144][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 2 - STA_START
[  2313][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 4 - STA_CONNECTED
Enabling IPv6
.
[  2620][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 7 - STA_GOT_IP
[  2620][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1098] _eventCallback(): STA IP: 192.168.1.3, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 192.168.1.1
.
wifi connected
[  4035][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 8 - STA_GOT_IP6
[  4774][D][HTTPClient.cpp:263] beginInternal(): unexpected protocol: https, expected http
[  4775][D][HTTPClient.cpp:303] beginInternal(): protocol: https, host: www.google.com port: 443 url: /
[  4781][D][HTTPClient.cpp:598] sendRequest(): request type: 'GET' redirCount: 0

[  5035][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 8 - STA_GOT_IP6
[  9829][I][ssl_client.cpp:112] start_ssl_client(): select returned due to timeout 5000 ms for fd 48
[  9830][E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:144] connect(): start_ssl_client: -1
[  9833][D][HTTPClient.cpp:1163] connect(): failed connect to www.google.com:443
[  9840][W][HTTPClient.cpp:1483] returnError(): error(-1): connection refused
HTTP code: -1
[  9858][D][HTTPClient.cpp:408] disconnect(): tcp is closed
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm having this issue now, and it's pretty much what you're describing.

Comment: They said it is pending from the development. It will be solved in ESP 3.0 version. Follow this roadmap for update : https://github.com/orgs/espressif/projects/3/views/14. There are other alternatives on there GitHub page but are quite complicated. You can dig into that, I didn't.